# Phonegap blackberry could not find js/webworks.js and screen not centered

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm testing the phonegap sample application in the blackberry simulator.

I have two problems:

**First:** The page is not centered in the screen of the device, It's always on top. And if the "Device is ready" label is actually a button, I can't get it to fire.

**Second:** In the console of the emulator it says:

```
FRIDG: could not find js/webworks.js.
```

I looked that file in the js folder and it's not there.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Like, what do you mean the page isn't centred on the device and always on top?  What CSS and HTML have you set-up to expect one behaviour but experiencing the other?  The webworks.js is important to be there but depends on the platform.  Are you using Mac OS X or Windows?  As much sample code and information you can provide would go a long way and I can help you more easily.  Thanks!

Comment: The js/webworks.js gets generated when you build the project using the cordova command line tools or ant tools. ie, typing "ant blackberry build" will build the project and then place the webworks.js file in the js/ directory.

Comment: no file generated.... I'm almost stepping out of Blackberry development with phonegap

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm encountering the second problem...